# Sorting dictionary list values

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, defaultdict

i have the following defaultdict

```
(<tpe 'list'>, {'one' : ['1a','3f','2z'], 'two' : ['6x','9d','2q']})
```

is there a way such that my values per key will be sorted and have the new defaultdict as:

```
(<tpe 'list'>, {'one' : ['1a','2z','3f'], 'two' : ['2q','6x','9d']})
```

Comment: Your `two` array looks wrong. That's not even a proper dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my one-liner using dict generator approach:

```
dict((k,sorted(v)) for k, v in d.items())
```

**Output:**

```
d = {'one': ['1a', '3f', '2z'], 'two': ['6x', '9d', '2q']}
dict((k,sorted(v)) for k, v in d.items())
Out[81]: {'one': ['1a', '2z', '3f'], 'two': ['2q', '6x', '9d']}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sort the dictionary list values like that:

```
my_dict = {'one': ['1a', '3f', '2z'], 'two': ['6x', '9d', '2q']}
print my_dict
for key, value in my_dict.iteritems():
    my_dict[key] = sorted(value)
print my_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the values of the dictionary and call the sort method on each one.

```
d = {'one': ['1a', '3f', '2z'], 'two': ['6x', '9d', '2q']}
for v in d.itervalues():
    v.sort()

print d
# OUT: {'two': ['2q', '6x', '9d'], 'one': ['1a', '2z', '3f']}
```